# What exactly does delta mean in the gradient descent algorithm?

Tags: math, machine-learning, linear-regression, recursive-descent

As on the picture:

[image]

Could someone help me understand what exactly what delta means in the gradient descent algorithm?

Comment: If my intuition is correct, you sort of take a small step in the direction of the gradient. The gradient is a vector, consisting of all the partial derivatives, and points in the direction that the function grows the most... sort of...

Comment: You should refresh your basics in multivariate calculus before attempting to understand gradient decent algorithm, as this (the partial derivative) is a very fundamental operator.

Comment: Yes, i should. Thank You for informations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term is a [derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative) with respect to the `theta 0`.

- Mark `theta` as coordinate on X-axis (let it be A)
- Find corresponding coordinate on Y-axis (let it be B) so the point belongs to the function J
- Draw tangent line to that function at the point (A, B)
- The derivative is the slope of this tangent line.

[image]

The derivative is used to control two aspects of the cost function (J function) minimization:

- direction - sign of the slope tells you in which direction you should move along the X-axis in order to converge J
- rate - magnitude of the slope tells you how fast you should move

Comment: Thank You for that explanation. I will try to built in this knowledge to my mind.

Comment: "of the theta", or "with respect with theta_0"?

Answer (score 4):

This is a partial derivative with respect to theta_0.

Comment: Thank You for that. I will take this information and start to calculating math.